# Android specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio

Im trying to generate signed APK Using AndroidStudio but I get this error:

```
    Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageRelease'.
> File 'com.pachu.fartsound' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.
```

i dont know if you need it but there is my build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pachu.fartsounds"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
}
```

Comment: any idea how to generate unsigned release apk!

Comment: .. applicationId "com.pachu.fartsounds" .. lol

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go to Build -> Generate Signed APK. Create your key (or choose existing) -> next -> next -> done!

If you want to do it "hard way" you need to specify already created release key into signingConfigs before buildTypes. Something like this:

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("/yourkey.jks") //check that the file exists
            storePassword "YourPassword"
            keyAlias "YourAlias"
            keyPassword "YourPassword"
        }
    }
```

But this is useless somewhat. Because Android Studio provides very simple and easy way to create a signed APK file ready for publishing. And also specifying your key's password into the build.gradle file... - it isn't advisable to do it in terms of security.

Comment: "But this is useless somewhat". I strongly disagree. If you have to build several debug/release versions with different configurations of your app than this is VERY useful.

Comment: if your doing this from your keystore.properties file 'storeFile your_keystore.jks'

Comment: if multiple people (e.g. dev team) have access to a repo with all the source, then they might as well have access to the keys/passphrases that obfuscate that release apk - that's the only way they can build and test a release build, with /data upgrade testing and whatnot. Or else you have the added flow of having the "Build Master" release for you to actually test this. I believe this should be left to organizational policy but it does make dev work a lot harder without much benefit. Or you can provide access to a jenkins interface that allows you this without key visibility

Answer (score 7):

My key was in

```
APPROOT/myKey.jks
```

Whilst the gradle was looking in

```
APPROOT/app/myKey.jks
```

I think you specify that second path on the second dialogue when you generate the signed apk, but I haven't checked it out, can someone confirm?

Comment: I was using the instructions based off of the RN Generating Signed APK (http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html), and I had a similar issue, where it was looking in android/app. In my ~/.gradle/gradle.properties, I changed the MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE to point to ../../my-release.key.keystore, since I built the key with keytool at the approot. It may be easier to build the keyfile in the android/app folder, and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try rebuilding the project. So go to Build-> Clean Project. 
Then generate the signed APK file again (Build -> Generate Signed APK).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you write the extension of the keystore file when firstly creating.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error. The mistake I made was storing the keystore in the application's `"app"` package and  providing the same path to android studio.

Just remove the keystore and place another than your android application's `""` package.

Answer (score 0):

Change Permissions for the app folder to 777 for everyone.The reason is because Android Studio is failing to write to the folder