# Apache Cordova getting errors when compile application

Tags: java, apache-cordova

I want to create an app. But when compiling, I got the following errors. Can someone help me?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':packageRelease'.
> File 'c:\Users\pv\Desktop\finals' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' is not a file.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':packageRelease'.
> File 'c:\Users\pv\Desktop\finals' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' is not a file.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25211444/5860648