# (?) question mark folder generated in android project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have got this issue  **"File '/home/likewise-open/INTELGAIN/rajeev.s/AndroidStudioProjects/YourFood/app/?/.android/debug.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist"** whenever I try to run the project.

I haven't generated any keystore file for this project. If you know the solution then Please reply.

Please check the below screenshot for more information ->

[image]

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25212759/2196176)

Comment: Try rebuilding the project. go to Build-> Clean Project.

Comment: @Marzouk I have tried the clean project, but not working.

Comment: @Sunny but i haven't created any keystore file.I have created a fresh project.

Comment: Make sure you are in the correct build configs and you not trying to generate a key